# Copying domain (and only domain) between Esri geodatabases?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, domains

Sometimes I have the need to copy a domain(s) from one geodatabase to another (without the featureclass or table).

In the past, I have accomplished this in a few different ways, but each method is not as straightforward as I think it could be (or maybe there's a *CopyDomain* tool that I've missed).

What method do you use to accomplish this?

Comment: I know of at least 2 additional methods: maybe not "accepted answer" worthy, but definitely reputation worthy.  I'll post them in a few days if no one else provides them as answers.

Comment: Do post the additional solutions, the community will vote up if they are worthy :)

Comment: On several occasions I've had to explain to non-GIS DBA's how domains are like a table, but are not stored as a table that can be accessed through SQL.  Maybe answers to this should be in language a non-GIS DBA can understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14729

This is an ArcCatalog Extension that allows you to copy domains between geodatabases.

I believe it is only up to date for 9.3.1 SP1, so it may not work with ArcGIS 10.

Comment: +1  I am on ArcGIS 10, but I deliberately left the question open to any version.   I did get the 9.3.1 extension to work in ArcCatalog 10. I didn't get the new command on the context menu, but I was able to add the command to a toolbar and use it that way.

Comment: Ok, glad that worked.  You should let the extension author know about the context menu command not working in ArcCatalog 10.

Comment: I did notify the author (crickets so far).  Also, I applied SP1 to ArcGIS 10 on friday.  Now the copy domains arccatalog extension errors when ArcCatalog starts up.

Comment: That makes sense, hopefully he'll update it soon.

Answer (score 16):

For coded value domains, I'll do a [Domain To Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000022000000.htm) from the source geodatabase and then do a [Table To Domain](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Table_To_Domain/001700000025000000/) into the new geodatabase.

I don't know of a way to this for the range domains. You can do a [Domain To Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000022000000.htm), but the [Table To Domain](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Table_To_Domain/001700000025000000/) always comes in as a coded value domain.

Comment: I just used the Domain to Table and Table to Domain tools this morning and they worked great.

Answer (score 3):

This method is more hacky and only practical for 1 or a few domains.

1. In the original geodatabase, create
   a dummy featureclass with a dummy
   field that matches the field data
   type of the domain that you wish to
   copy.
2. Copy/Paste the dummy featureclass
   into the new geodatabase and don't
   delete it until you've assigned the
   domain to a field in another
   featureclass.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a quick command line arcobjects exe based on some [vba code that I found last week](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000002000000). It's not complicated code.

Ex[e is here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156285/CopyDomain.zip).
[AVI movie here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156285/CopyDomain_Example.avi).

Fine print: The exe is compiled to 10.0 / ArcEditor license (the license is part is hard-coded for now).

[image]

Comment: I tried this out but I get exception errors, `CopyDomain.exe canvec_blank.gdb  target.gdb *
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040228
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040228`. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but are you an ArcEditor license?  That was a quick&dirty tool, so it's probably not the most elegant tool.  Do you have Visual Studio? The source is here: http://code.google.com/p/umbriel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FUmbriel.ArcGIS.Geodatabase%2FCopyDomain

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method to export/import domains that uses **XML Workspace Documents**.

### Requirements

- ArcGIS Desktop 10.X.X
- ArcGIS Pro latest (tested)
- Notepad++, Notepad, or your favorite text editor

### Procedure

#### Export XML from Source

1. Select your source geodatabase
2. Export an *XML Workspace Document*

[image: export]

3. Export the schema only. Metadata is optional (red arrow).

[image: schema only]

#### Edit XML

The dataset schema is deleted in the step.

1. Open the XML file.
2. (optional) Turn on word wrap to make everything easier to see.
3. Delete *everything* between the `<DatasetDefinitions xsi:type='esri:ArrayOfDataElement'>` and the `</DatasetDefinitions>` tags. It should look something like this:

[image: xml edits]

4. Leave everything else alone.
5. Save the XML file

#### Import to Target

1. Find/Create the new geodatabase
2. Import the *XML Workspace Document...*
3. Select the edited XML and go.
4. Done.

### Troubleshooting

- The Esri XML workspace specification is very specific. If the import step gives an error, there is probably a schema error. Review the XML or just export it again and repeat. Don't remove any extra carets or line breaks.